# .htaccess Syntax: Rewrite with anything before/after query

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a page that currently resides on "http://domain.com/subdir/folder1". There's quite a few directories after /folder1/ such as "folder1/bananas/stock/" "folder1/apples/stock/order/", etc. I was trying to find a way that would grab the page from "domain.com/subdir/folder1/bananas" for example if I had typed in "domain.com/subdir/fruits/bananas", keeping "fruits" in the URL after the redirect.

This is the code I've been able to come up with:
(I actually don't even know what percentage of it is correct)

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/subdir/fruits/.*$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /subdir/folder1/$1
```

I haven't been able to properly find the syntax that would allow any subdirectory before or after "fruits" to be written respectively replacing "folder1". There are times where the URL could be "domain.com/customer/subdir/fruits", so my goal was trying to find the syntax as well for "everything before this", instead of the ^ which just says everything after the domain, if I'm not mistaken.

As always, I appreciate any time or help dedicated to the issue. Thank you!

**Edit**: Here's another few examples of my goal:

```
User types into webaddress:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/fruits/bananas/stock/refund
page gets information from:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/folder1/bananas/stock/refund
User sees URL in address box:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/fruits/bananas/stock/refund
/* -------- */
User types into webaddress:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/customer/fruits/apples/review
Page gets information from:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/customer/folder1/apples/review
User sees URL in address box:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/customer/fruits/apples/review
/* -------- */
User types into webaddress:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/customer/fruits/cherries/season-listing
Page gets information from:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/customer/folder1/cherries/season-listing
User sees URL in address box:
http://www.domain.com/subdir/customer/fruits/cherries/season-listing
```

Comment: It's difficult to understand what you mean with `folder1` and its relationship to `fruits`. Can you provide 2 or 3 examples each showing the URL your end user sees in the browser address and the internal URL it should be rewritten to?

Comment: No problem; Added a few more examples into the post.